# CollectionView Xamarin How to speed rendering

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list to show where we show repeat information from SQlite database to user. In this we show basically the product price, name and type. Usually a user will have 10-15 of such records.

Problem is it take 10+ sec to display the list. Now, the architecture of application. On page load of Shell application we fetch the information from web request and store that in SQlite and then Bind the Result from Sqlite StackLayout with Bindable Property. But it took more than 10-11 Sec to display us.

So we change it to `Grid` with `Bindable` property and results are same. Though I don't like `CollectionView` (as I found their select property weird. ) We use `CollectionView` with dataTemplate as Grid (as we have some tabular information to show) . The results still take same 10+ secs to load up.

i.e. I use Stacklayout, Grid, CollectionView, it take that much time. We are not using the `ObservableCollection` to bind, but our class elements are all `INotifyPropertyChanged`. So, I try to disable it but still even when I do not inherity `INotifyPropertyChanged` and remove "OnPropertyChanged" calls it still take same time.

However, when I reduce the information to just show the name of product (through binding) it reduce to 5 secs. Which is still a lot as a Collection View with just 10 records and showing one Bindable Grid showing result in 5 second is lot more than expected. I understand my other data (which call functions) maybe slowing it down but can we reduce those 5 second somehow?

I cannot share much of class, but some of properties are pretty straight forward Property with INotifyPropertyChange on string or int values.

Here is Code for loading CollectionView

```
  public async Task LoadSearch()
        {
            CurrentState = LayoutState.Loading;
            try
            {
                var o = await PatientMedicine.FetchPatientMedicine();
                if (o)
                {
                    var _sr = (await DBCoreAsync.GetDataAsync<PatientMedicine>())?.OrderBy(x => x.PatientMedID).ToList();
                    if (_sr != null)
                    {
                        SearchResults = _sr;
                    }
                    CurrentState = LayoutState.Success;
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentState = LayoutState.Error;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CurrentState = LayoutState.Error;
            }

        }
```

Here is Collection itself.

```
 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem">
                                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"  />
                                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>                                        
                                        <Grid Padding="0,7" ColumnSpacing="0">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"  />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <BoxView BackgroundColor="{Binding LowStock, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorReverse}}" CornerRadius="5,0,5,0" />

                                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="0"                                            
                                                  Padding="10,5" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryLight2}">                                                
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Medicine.RxIcon}" ></Image>
                                                <Label Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource GeneralLabelBlack}" Text="{Binding Medicine.MedicineName}"></Label>
                                                <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.NavigateToMedicineReminder, Source={x:Reference Name=MedicineListPageName}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                                                            BackgroundColor="Transparent" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" ImageSource="{FontImage FontFamily=FontAwesomeSolid, Glyph=&#xf304;, Color={StaticResource Primary},Size=16}" ></Button>

                                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                                                                Source="{StaticResource ImageSourceIconClockOpenHand}"></Image>
                                                <Label Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding RepeatStatusFormatted}"></Label>

                                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" 
                                                                Source="{StaticResource ImageSourceIconStock}"></Image>
                                                <Label Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding StockAndRequirement}"></Label>

                                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" 
                                                                Source="{StaticResource ImageSourceIconClock}"></Image>
                                                <Label Grid.Column ="1"  Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding NextReminder}"></Label>

                                                <Label Grid.Column ="0"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Medicine.AilmentString}"></Label>

                                                <Label Grid.Column ="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="5" IsVisible="{Binding LowStock}" Text="Stock running low. Order a refill now" HorizontalOptions="End"></Label>
                                                <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.AddtoCart, Source={x:Reference Name=MedicineListPageName}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                                                            BackgroundColor="Transparent" IsVisible="{Binding LowStock}"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" ImageSource="{FontImage FontFamily=FontAwesomeSolid, Glyph=&#xf217;, Color={StaticResource Primary},Size=16}" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                        
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
```

To add more information: I am okay with Internet load time which is <=1.5 seconds the time I calculate and show here is exclusively for When I set the ViewModel to Values from temporary variable to main variable I did it just to see if DB access is slow or not. (to step it out). I have my control inside a StackLayout that use `Xamarin Community Toolkit` statelayout.

Also I go through MS's Suggestion on optimizing performance about Compile XAML etc, but since it is new App using Xamarin Forms 5.0 I don't think it is problem as it is already set by default.

Comment: You have the App. You have the IDE, you have the power to profile your App and figure out where the time is spent. With a wall of text, we are not really able to help you unless you provide a minimal reproducible sample. Otherwise, it is just guesses. However, a qualified guess, would be that the UI is not at fault, but rather how you load your data. If the UI had issues, then it would appear as jank, and not 10-15 seconds of initial loading time.

Comment: Profiling is available on Visual Studio Prof or higher, but I am using Community Edition. I have debug all steps, and as in my wall of text I mention that Loading from internet is not problem (that time is acceptable). it is when we set a List<MyClass> to output of Sqlite it start rendering the UI and that is where it take time to render. Or Maybe you can tell me how I profile app to see issue myself?

Comment: Have you tried with some dummy data? Do images (icons?) affect the loading speed? And two Grids can be merged, somehow?

Comment: I cannot get 2 grid to merge properly as then I cannot get the GAP between each row visible. That is another problem though. I thought about image since we are showing icon can be problem that is why I convert them to staticResource and use from there, but it hardly make an difference.

Comment: @SumitGupta Maybe you can try to use [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) to load your image, load images quickly & easily on Xamarin.

Comment: But I don't have image, only some Icon that I load from FontAwesome Icon font.

Comment: 1) If you remove ALL XAML inside `CollectionView.ItemTemplate`, how long does it take? If that's still 5 seconds, then it isn't a XAML problem, it is somewhere else. 2) *"when I reduce the information to just show the name of product"* - but did you also reduce the XAML to the absolute bare minimum? No Grids.  `<DataTemplate><Label Text={Binding ProductName}/></DataTemplate>` If that is fast, then gradually add back in your XAML, find out what takes 5 seconds with only ProductName. 3) As a test, replace all "Auto" row heights to fixed values. If its quick, then layout time is the problem.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thank your suggestion help me identify that one of property that I am setting in my grid is major reason for slowness.